# nginx redirect a url into a complete different pattern

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

In my nginx I want to redirect the `/media/api/static/terms.html` into `/terms-of-use` and my nginx has the following configuration:

```
 listen 80;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html/website;

    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server_tokens off;
    sendfile off;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    location /manifest.json {
        default_type application/x-web-app-manifest+json;
    }

    location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
        default_type application/json;
    }

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include   fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass website:9000;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;

    }

    location /robots/robots-gr.txt {
       default_type text/plain;
    }

    location /robots/robots-cy.txt {
       default_type text/plain;
    }

    rewrite ^/robots.txt$ /robots/robots-gr.txt last;

    location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|svg|pdf)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        tcp_nodelay off;

        ## Set the OS file cache.
        open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
        open_file_cache_valid 45s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
  }
}
```

I attempted the following:

```
    location /media/api/static/terms.html {
      return 301 /terms-of-use
    }
```

But the url does not 301 redirects. Also I tried the following:

```
    location /media/api/static/terms.html {
        rewrite  $scheme://$host/terms-of-use last;
    }
```

But still I have no 301 redirection. Do you have any idea hot to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matching locations have a greater priority over the prefix locations. That's why your

```
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|svg|pdf)$ {
    ...
}
```

takes priority over the

```
location /media/api/static/terms.html {
    return 301 /terms-of-use
}
```

The full algorithm to choose the location for the request processing described in the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

You can solve this several ways:

- Use exact location match:

  ```
  location = /media/api/static/terms.html {
      return 301 /terms-of-use;
  }
  ```
- Use the `^~` location modifier:

  ```
  location ^~ /media/api/static/terms.html {
      return 301 /terms-of-use;
  }
  ```
- Use a rewrite rule in the `server` context:

  ```
  rewrite ^/media/api/static/terms\.html$ /terms-of-use permanent;
  ```